# Difference Between Random Walks

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, random-walk, binomial-distribution

I am considering 2 formulations of random walks that both supposedly converge to Brownian motion. Let $\mu >0$ be the drift and $\sigma>0$ be the standard deviation (volatility). Consider a discretization with $t_0 = 0$ and $t_n = nh$ for some small step size $0<h\ll1$. Further define a binomial random variable 
$$B(\pm1,p) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ with probability } p \\ -1, \text{ with probability } 1- p\end{cases}$$
then fix $x_0$ and consider
\begin{align}
x_{t_{n+1}} = x_{(n+1)h} &= x_{nh} + \mu h + \sigma \sqrt{h}B\big(\pm1,\frac{1}{2}\big) \\
x_{t_{n+1}} = x_{(n+1)h} &= x_{nh} + \sigma \sqrt{h}B\big(\pm1, \frac{1}{2}(1 + \frac{\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{h})\big)
\end{align}
I know that both of the converge to Brownian motion $BM(x_0,\mu,\sigma^2)$ in the limit that $h\rightarrow 0$. I am just wondering what the difference is between the formulations or can we somehow scale the binomial distribution so that they look more similar?.

Answer (score 1):

You have two walks that are biased so that the particle tends to move to the right. The first walk is biased by adding a constant $\mu h$ to a symmetric Bernoulli distribution. The second walk is biased by making the Bernoulli distribution asymmetric.

In either case the particle is expected to move $\mu h$ units to the right during one step of the random walk.
So it seems to me the distributions already *are* scaled in order to make this true.

Have you done any simulations or convolutions to see what the distribution of states looks like after a large number of steps? How dissimilar were the two results?